# ALTER TABLE only supports altering schema for tables while "TableName" is a EXTERNAL TABLE

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new in BigQuery and struggling. In SQL, ALTER TABLE can add,drop columns. But in BigQuery it shows I cannot modify an external table(imported from Drive). Can someone help with that? How can I alter an external table?

Tried to use ALTER TABLE.

Answer (score 1):

This is a BigQuery limitation since as mentioned in this [BigQuery External Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-tables#limitations) documentation,

> You **cannot modify external data tables using DML or other methods**. External tables are **read-only for BigQuery**.

This means that on BigQuery side, the external table are only to retrieve data through SELECT queries.

The only way to update the external table is by updating the actual source of the external table (eg. Updating the actual CSV file from your GCS bucket given that you used [wildcard](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/wildcards) in your GCS URI as source (in BigQuery) so that it will be dynamic and not static on a specific filename).