# Is it possible to label external tables in BigQuery using SQL?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Trying to label tables in our BigQuery estate and running into issues labelling external tables using SQL.

Using the following statement, we can label most tables apart from GCS external ones.

```sql
alter table `project.dataset.table` set options (labels = [('test' , 'label')])
```

Error when trying to run this on external tables:

```
Invalid value: ALTER TABLE SET OPTIONS only supports setting options for tables, while table is a(n) external at [1:1]
```

Looking into this, [we found out that we can't use DML statements with external tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74377014/alter-table-only-supports-altering-schema-for-tables-while-tablename-is-a-exte).

However, in the console, we're able to label the same external table:
[image: able to add labels in GCP console]

So we're wondering if there's any way we can use SQL to label tables we have in BigQuery?

Comment: It seems to be an unsupported operation by the SQL language today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery **does not** natively support the labeling of external tables using **SQL statements**. Labeling is typically done at the dataset or table level within BigQuery, but it's not available for external tables.

**DML operations**, such as the use of statements like `ALTER TABLE SET OPTIONS`, are not applicable to external tables within BigQuery. External tables in BigQuery essentially serve as references to data residing outside the BigQuery environment, such as in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) or other supported external data repositories. Because BigQuery lacks direct control over the metadata associated with external data, employing DML statements to configure options or assign labels to external tables is not feasible.

If you wish to assign labels, the recommended approach is to manage these labels or metadata directly within **GCS**. You can accomplish this by adding custom metadata to GCS objects through object metadata features. However, please note that these labels will not seamlessly integrate into BigQuery's native labeling system. To apply labels or annotations to your external tables in BigQuery, it may be necessary to maintain a separate record or catalog that correlates external table names with corresponding labels or metadata. Subsequently, you can query this catalog alongside your BigQuery queries to access the required information.

Comment: That's understandable, but how is it still possible to label external tables via the console?